# Storyboards and UISplitViewController not working under iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uistoryboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an app that must support iOS 7-9. The views are laid out in storyboard, it's a tab bar controller, with each tab containing a split view controller.

Everything works fine, except with an iPhone running iOS 7. I have the following code to collapse the split view controller to show the detail:

```
UINavigationController *splitNav = self.navigationController;
UISplitViewController *split = splitNav.splitViewController;
split.delegate = self;
```

But on the iOS 7 iPhone, split is nil (as there is no split view controller under iPhone on iOS 7) so `splitViewController: shouldHideViewController: inOrientation:` never gets called and I'm stuck in a weird state.

I tried push the detail controller onto the navigation controller manually, but the view never loads (just get a black screen), although the controller logic executes.

Can I either set that behavior with with storyboard instead of in code or is there some other way to reference the detail of a split view controller that doesn't exist?